# Can't create new line after specific comment in Html using Perl

Tags: html, regex, perl, parsing

I have the following html-

```
<a href="http://foo.com/User">User</a>: comment ;
```

This html is used repeatedly through the entire html document and I have managed to parse out all the comments into a csv, however the comments are getting merged into one massive string. I am trying to use a `RegEx` to create a new line after every comment finishes however I am having problems.

I used this 
`$comment =~ s/\,//g;` which put all the comments into one massive string instead of individual cells without it, however how can I get a new line after each comment ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$comment =~ s/\,//g;` replaces all occurrences of `,` with nothing. If you want to replace it with something you place it between the `//`. Like `$comment =~ s/\,/foo/g;` to replace it with foo. If you want to insert a linebreak just write your linebreak character intstead of foo.

Comment: Can you do the same when using @keywords =~

Comment: No need to escape the comma. In fact, no need to use a regular expression at all if you're just replacing a fixed piece of text.